# How exclude date from input date vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date, input

start from here:

`<input type="date" name="chooseDay" min="2019-08-05" max="2019-09-13">`

how can I make the 7th, 20th of Aug, and 1st September not available?

Thanks

Comment: Not do-able, with the native date picker inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could immediately `null`-out the value, if the chosen value is not allowed.

In the example below, I added a data attribute called `unallowed` that is a JSON array containing invalid dates. Upon changing the value, that data attribute is access via the element's `dataset` to determine if the value is valid.

Unfortunately, you cannot make individual dates within the min-max range disabled on the calendar picker.

```js
const chooseDay = document.querySelector('input[name="chooseDay"]');

const handleDateChange = ({ target: dateField }) => {
  const
    { dataset: { unallowed = '[]' }, value } = dateField,
    unallowedDates = JSON.parse(unallowed),
    valid = !unallowedDates.includes(value);
  if (!valid) { dateField.value = null; }
  dateField.classList.toggle('invalid', !valid);
};

chooseDay.addEventListener('change', handleDateChange);
```

```css
.invalid { border-color: #F77; background: #FEE; }
```

```html
<input type="date" name="chooseDay"
  min="2019-08-05" max="2019-09-13" value="2019-08-05"
  data-unallowed='["2019-08-07","2019-08-20","2019-09-01"]' />
```